# PHP-based self-hosted file drop software?

Tags: file-manager, looking-for-a-script

Does anyone know of any open source (or priced for SMB) self-hosted alternatives to services like DropSend, YouSendIt, etc?

I'd like something that auto-removes files after a set period of time, generates links to the uploaded files and shows a history for each user with upload privileges.  That said, I'd be happy to look at any options that are available.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE:  Just to clarify, I'm looking for more of a finished app that allows for files to be hosted locally than an upload script.  The closest thing I've found is this: http://quixly.com/

Answer (score 1):

all php, all open source:

https://github.com/MasterEx/myloader

http://www.webdice.org/uber_uploader/

http://www.energyscripts.com/Products/product2.html

Answer (score 1):

A couple others:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openupload/

http://uber-uploader.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be Drupal based.  It can do all that you listed.  Drupal has great permissions, and tracking (in many different ways).  If you have more specific questions about Drupal, and maybe what modules or coding would be needed, just ask.

Comment: Well, in 2011 that counts for nearly every still-maintained CMS/CMF.

Comment: no, I very much disagree

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for in regards to you hosting it yourself, but http://www.transferbigfiles.com/ provides a free Mac and Windows file sending service similar to yousendit.

They do have a free plan, but it has some size limitations. Their professional plans work really well with their desktop applications though.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looks good.  I've actually settled on something, though not open-source or self-hosted, it will do the job better than anything else I could fine.  It's at http://fluxiom.com

Comment: Cool, no problem. Best of luck. Cheers